# Android Studio Key store password not visible

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio 3.2.1. In Windows 10 when generating signed APK in the first window the options (radio buttons) is not visible and in the second window Key store password and Key password is not visible. In Windows 7 it is ok.
Do anybody know why?
Thanks

[Generate Signed Bundle or APK1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txcYt.jpg)
[Generate Signed Bundle or APK2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBlmB.jpg)

Comment: have you set up a key store password for that project before, if so was it on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, I have set up key store pasword before. But on other computer. I can select Key store path but after selecting key the key store password edit and key password edit are still not visible and cannot be edited. On win 7 is everithing OK.

Comment: try selecting the .jks file using the module window

Comment: I have .keystore file. I am not understand what is module window. Thanks

Comment: check you screenshot in that you will find a tab called module  thats the place where you have to use it to select your .jks file

Comment: Do You mean in "Generate Signed Bundle or APK" window? The disabled combobox Module with value app? I have .keystore file. When I create new app in android studio, edits are visible and can be edited...

Comment: I am sorry my bad under Module there is an option called "Key store path" please select the choose existing under it and select the .jks file that will have your already generated keys

Comment: It is still the same. I have selected .keystore file in "Key store path" and edits are still not visible and editable...

Comment: can you add a screenshot

Comment: I updated the image Generate Signed Bundle or APK2 in the question...

Comment: I dont know why in the firts window are not visible radio buttons Android App Bundle / APK...

Comment: When I create new application, it is the same problem...

Comment: I can see in the second screenshot that you selected the keystore what happens after you press next?

Comment: Error box with please specify the poassword for key store. But I cannot write it.

Answer (score 3):

I has absolutely the same problem.
Simply restarting Android Studio solved it.